# Placing the label of the form center in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm very new to twitter bootstrap and I'm struggling to place my forms in center.

I have a code like this in here:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="pagination-centered">
        <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <form action="/payment-init" method="POST">
          <fieldset>
            <legend>Merchant CheckOut Page</legend>
            <label>Product Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." name="productName" value="Samsung Mobile Phone"/>
            <label>Amount</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter the amount in rupees..." name="amount" required="true" />
            <label>Merchant Name</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Merchant name" name="merchantId" required = "true" />
            <label>Customer Email</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="test@gmail.com" name="email" required = "true" />
            <br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

The output of this looks like below:

[image]

I wish to move the `label` (i.e Product Name, Amount etc) to the left-top corner of the textbox's. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `float: left; text-align: left;` If that's not helping put some CSS code into the post :) I can't tell the fix form that screenshot :)

Answer (score 2):

To place the label on the left-top corner of each textbox you need also to make each textbox fill all available width. So do the following:

```
.pagination-centered label {
  text-align:left;
}

.pagination-centered input {
  width: 100%;
}
```